# How to write an Excel file with a formatted date in the header, and formatted columns?

Tags: sas

I want to export a dataset into an Excel file from SAS, like shown below:

```
Claim_id  State    Suffix   Policy   Amount
125       CA         231    cyt     $58,000.00
458       dd         789    ghu     $78,961.00
458       lk         586    lk         -$56.00
785       ga         712    js         -$89.00
```

It needs to have a header like such: 
"As of [current month name] [current year].', for instance "As of January 2017".

Also if the amount is negative, it needs to show in the red color.

Answer (score 2):

### Title with today's Date in Month Name - Year format:

```
%let today_month = %sysfunc(today(), monname8.);
%let today_year = %sysfunc(today(), year4.);

%put &today_month. &today_year.;

title "As of &today_month. &today_year.";
```

### Setting a column in Excel to a custom format:

```
/* This line goes into your PROC PRINT or PROC REPORT */
var amount / style(column)={tagattr="format: $#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"};
```

To tweak the format, in Excel, right click on the cell, go to Format Cells -> Custom, create your format, and paste the string into the `"format: "`part.

### Example with `ODS Excel`:

```
data test;
    input Claim_id  Amount;
datalines;
125 58000
458 78961
458 -56
785 -89
;
run;

%let today_month = %sysfunc(today(), monname8.);
%let today_year = %sysfunc(today(), year4.);

%put &today_month. &today_year.;

ods excel file='output path and file name here.xlsx' 
    options(embedded_titles="yes");

proc print data=test noobs;
    title "As of &today_month. &today_year.";
    var claim_id;
    var amount 
         / style(column)={tagattr="format: $#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"};
    run;

ods excel close;
```

Result:

[image: Excel output example]

Note that `ODS EXCEL` was experimental in 9.4M2 and became production in 9.4M3. To use the older `ods tagsets.excelxp`, which is XML but appears as an Excel file, simply swap that in for `ods excel`:

```
ods tagsets.excelxp file='output path and file name here.xlsx' 
        options(embedded_titles="yes");;

... code here ...

ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

Sources:

http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2014/09/21/ods-excel-and-proc-export-xlsx/ https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings16/SAS5642-2016.pdf http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/366-2013.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use `ODS EXCEL`, which ships with SAS 9.4 TS1M2 I believe.  That would let you do exactly what you're asking.

If you don't have that version, you might do the same with `tagsets.excelxp`, though that doesn't create a normal-excel-file-type file; it would be an xml file that might need a further step to process.